# CSP Whitelist like ignored. How to set it?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, csp

I'm trying to set the CSP whitelist for Magento. I tried in many ways but I'm not able to make it works.

The module is enabled but `csp_whitelist.xml` **seems like ignored**. After changed the file I run, of course, *setup:upgrade* and I *cleared the cache*.

#### My configuration:

- Magento 2.4.0 in Developer mode served by Apache
- Varnish Cache in front of Apache
- Nginx as reverse proxy and SSL Termination in front of Varnish

---

## The CSP module

This is the `app/code/Vendor/Module/` I created:

`registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

`etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

`etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
            <mode>
                <storefront>
                    <report_uri></report_uri>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </storefront>
                <admin>
                    <report_uri></report_uri>
                    <report_only>1</report_only>
                </admin>
            </mode>
        </csp>
    </default>
</config>
```

`etc/csp_whitelist.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="default-src">
            <values>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="googletagmanager.com" type="host">googletagmanager.com</value>
                <value id="google" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="trustedshops" type="host">*.trustedshops.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="addthis.com" type="host">*.addthis.com</value>
                <value id="s7.addthis.com" type="host">s7.addthis.com</value>
                <value id="m.addthis.com" type="host">m.addthis.com</value>
                <value id="addthis-analytics" type="host">z.moatads.com</value>
                <value id="addthis-cdn" type="host">*.addthisedge.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">apis.google.com</value>
                <value id="graph-facebook" type="host">graph.facebook.com</value>
                <value id="widgets-pinterest" type="host">widgets.pinterest.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="style-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesomecdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="img-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="googleadservices" type="host">*.googleadservices.com</value>
                <value id="google-analytics" type="host">*.google-analytics.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="vimeocdn" type="host">*.vimeocdn.com</value>
                <value id="data" type="host">'self' data:</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="paypal" type="host">*.paypal.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="font-src">
            <values>
                <value id="cloudflare" type="host">*.cloudflare.com</value>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="gstatic" type="host">*.gstatic.com</value>
                <value id="typekit" type="host">*.typekit.net</value>
                <value id="googleapis" type="host">*.googleapis.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesome" type="host">*.fontawesome.com</value>
                <value id="fontawesomecdn" type="host">*.bootstrapcdn.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="frame-src">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
                <value id="google.com" type="host">*.google.com</value>
                <value id="addthis.com" type="host">*.addthis.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>

        <policy id="form-action">
            <values>
                <value id="twitter.com" type="host">*.twitter.com</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer below a useful module or use and try it might help you.

[Module Link](https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_ext_csp)

With that, you can get CSP Violations Reports and you can eliminate accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a great module but it still doesn't work. It seems to be ignored this too. I got the same console errors, nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to run `magento fl32:csp:analyze`! Now it seems to partially work!

Comment: How can I add more rules? Running `magento fl32:csp:analyze` recognized almost all entries except one. How can I add it?